# Extract the original file name

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application in which user has an option to attach a file. The file is then stored in the database and the file name is appended with a few strings such as form name, request number and date. I want to extract the original file name from this file.

eg. A file name **Test_File.docx** is saved as **Test_File__ABC__123_01252017.docx**. I have written a code to extract the file name using the code but I feel that there are many redundant elements in my code. Can someone please let me know if there is an alternative or a better way to write this.
Here is my piece of code.

```
file = "Test_File__ABC__123_01252017.docx";
                int ix1 = file.LastIndexOf('_');
                int ix2 = ix1 > 0 ? file.LastIndexOf('_', ix1 - 1) : -1;
                int ix3 = ix2 > 0 ? file.LastIndexOf('_', ix2 - 1) : -1;
                int ix4 = ix3 > 0 ? file.LastIndexOf('_', ix3 - 1) : -1;
                int ix5 = ix4 > 0 ? file.LastIndexOf('_', ix4 - 1) : -1;
                int ix6 = ix5 > 0 ? file.LastIndexOf('_', ix5 - 1) : -1;

string Real_Name = file.Substring(0, ix6);
```

Real_Name contains the original file name "**Test_File**"

Comment: Can't you rely on the size of the appended name? Will it vary?

Comment: You can use `file.LastIndexOf("__", ...)` instead and avoid a lot of those lines.

Comment: Yes Daniel, the size of the appended name can vary. I cannot use "__" since I get a build error "Too many characters in character literal"

Comment: Save the original file name, form name, request number and date in separate columns.

Comment: @DourHighArch : That's not an option. It is an old application and this will require a lot of change.

Comment: @Daniel : any suggestions??

Comment: Welcome to C#.  You should know that in C#, ***the type of quotes you use matters.***  The function `int String.LastIndexOf( string value, int startIndex )` has existed since .Net framework 1.1, so you should definitely be able to use `"__"`.  But note that these are double quotes, not single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
string orgFileName = "Test__File__ABC__123__01252017.docx";
string[] fileNameParts = orgFileName.Split(new string[] { "__" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
string Real_Name = String.Join("__", fileNameParts.Take(fileNameParts.Length - 3));
```

Comment: What if the original file contains "__"?

Comment: @Joe: exactly my concern. However the only thing that's constant is that there will be exactly 3 "__" after the original file name.

Comment: I thought that constant is " __ " after real name. I've just edit my answer. Now real file name if all befor 3 " __ ". right?

Comment: @Gaurav Your example doesn't have “exactly 3” underscores; there is a single “_” after what I am guessing is “request number”. Either your example or comment is wrong.

Comment: @daniell89 : This didn't work. Assuming the file name is "Test__File__ABC__123__01252017.docx" , after the execution, it realFileName returns TestFile.

Comment: And what realFileName you expect?

Comment: @daniell89 I expect realFIleName to be "Test__File". Only the last three "__" should be removed.

Comment: @gauravsachdeva, Updated

Comment: @daniell89 : Yes, this works now.. Many thanks to all for the help..!!

Comment: @gauravsachdeva look at last update, I think its better :) only 3 lines  of code:)

Comment: @daniell89: Yes, The latest update worked like a charm.. Thank you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
file = "Test_File__ABC__123_01252017.docx";
            int ix1 = file.LastIndexOf("__");
            int ix2 = ix1 > 0 ? file.LastIndexOf("__", ix1 - 1) : -1;

string Real_Name = file.Substring(0, ix2);
```

Please notice that this: `"__"` is different from this `'__'`.

This is `string`: `"__"`
This is `char`: `'_'`